# Parameter and Functions in Bash

Tags: bash, parameters

Trying to get a function to work called grepme (in a script). its suppose to take 2 parameters that do the following:
a. Parameter 1 will specify the full path to the file you want to search
b. Parameter 2 will specify the text you would like to search for.

When I run this script nothing happens still new to scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
function grepme {
grep $1 $2
}

grepme "/home/user/testfile"
grepme "TEXT"
```

Comment: You do not call your function twice each time with one parameter. You need to call your function once with both parameters: `grepme "/home/user/testfile" "TEXT"` The positional arguments `$1` and `$2` refer to first and second parameter you have called the function with. That also means, for your described behavior, you need to call `grep` with `grep "$2" "$1"`, i.e. swap the order, its first positional argument is pattern, second argument is path.

Comment: Also, put double-quotes around parameter (and variable) references, e.g. `"$1"` instead of just `$1` (note that Ondrej K. did this in their comment). This doesn't matter for the simple example you gave, but for more complex search patterns and/or some filenames, failing to double-quote can produce bizarre results.